# How to handle uninstall intent on Android 6 and above?

Tags: android, android-intent, uninstallation, intentfilter

### Background

On my "[**app manager**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager)" app, I handled uninstall intent so that users could uninstall apps in the background, using root.

### The problem

Up to Android 5.x , all went well and worked fine, but it seems that starting from Android 6, things have changed and the same intent, even though the logs say is being used, cannot be used by the app.

### What I've tried

The manifest includes this intent-filter for the activity, as it always had:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="package"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

This is because of the docs, [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DELETE) and [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE), it says that those are what the framework uses.

I tried to separate the actions, and I tried to look at the logs, but it's exactly the same logs as before. Example:

> system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0
>   {act=android.intent.action.DELETE dat=package:me.scan.android.client
>   flg=0x10800000
>   cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity
>   (has extras)} from uid 10078 on display 0

It seems as if the framework already decided which app would handle the intent.

### The question

Is it possible to still handle uninstall-intent? Even with root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/+/9fef4f6dcd2ea4ed7686a8d21f858a7a8eaf317f), this was an intentional change first seen in the [marshmallow-release branch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/+log/marshmallow-release/AndroidManifest.xml) to disallow intercepting the package uninstall UI.

Comment: Where do you see it there? "Don't let others intercept the package uninstall UI." ? and can it be bypassed With root if needed?

Comment: It seems that there is a check in "isInstallRequestFromUnknownSource" function that says "Privileged apps are not considered an unknown source." . Moving the app to be a system app doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Seeing the commit in the log for a branch means that commit is in the branch, yes. Root does not allow you to override the `<intent-filter>` priority AFAIK.

Comment: So there is no way to handle this? How did you even find it so quickly?

Comment: I wouldn't have answered the question this way if I thought there was a way to get around the intentional change that explains exactly what you are seeing. Looking at the [blame for the AndroidManifest.xml that contains the UninstallerActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/+blame/marshmallow-release/AndroidManifest.xml) makes it straightforward to find the exact commit that last touched a line.

Comment: I meant: how did you find this link from what I've asked? How did you know where to look, and what to search for? Anyway, I'm marking this answer, and referring it to a post I've created, when I thought it's a bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206047